# Why can I initialize a List like an array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, initialization

Today I was surprised to find that in C# I can do:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Why can I do this? What constructor is called? How can I do this with my own classes? I know that this is the way to initialize arrays but arrays are language items and Lists are simple objects ...

Comment: This question may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744967/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-write-custom-object-initializers-for-new-data-types

Comment: Pretty awesome huh? You can do very similar code to initialize dictionaries as well: `{ { "key1", "value1"}, { "key2", "value2"} }`

Comment: From another view this array like initialization syntax gives us a reminder that underlying data type of a `List<int>` is actually an array only. I hate C# team for the fact that they not name it `ArrayList<T>` which sounds so obvious and natural.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This is part of the collection initializer syntax in .NET.  You can use this syntax on any collection you create as long as:

- It implements `IEnumerable` (preferably `IEnumerable<T>`)
- It has a method named `Add(...)`

What happens is the default constructor is called, and then `Add(...)` is called for each member of the initializer.

Thus, these two blocks are roughly identical:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

And

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>();
temp.Add(1);
temp.Add(2);
temp.Add(3);
List<int> a = temp;
```

You **can** call an alternate constructor if you want, for example to prevent over-sizing the `List<T>` during growing, etc:

```
// Notice, calls the List constructor that takes an int arg
// for initial capacity, then Add()'s three items.
List<int> a = new List<int>(3) { 1, 2, 3, }
```

Note that the `Add()` method need not take a single item, for example the `Add()` method for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` takes two items:

```
var grades = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        { "Suzy", 100 },
        { "David", 98 },
        { "Karen", 73 }
    };
```

Is roughly identical to:

```
var temp = new Dictionary<string, int>();
temp.Add("Suzy", 100);
temp.Add("David", 98);
temp.Add("Karen", 73);
var grades = temp;
```

So, to add this to your own class, all you need do, as mentioned, is implement `IEnumerable` (again, preferably `IEnumerable<T>`) and create one or more `Add()` methods:

```
public class SomeCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // implement Add() methods appropriate for your collection
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // your add logic    
    }

    // implement your enumerators for IEnumerable<T> (and IEnumerable)
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // your implementation
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it just like the BCL collections do:

```
public class MyProgram
{
    private SomeCollection<int> _myCollection = new SomeCollection<int> { 13, 5, 7 };    

    // ...
}
```

(For more information, see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx))

Comment: Good answer, though I note that it is not quite accurate to say "exactly identical" in your first example. It is exactly identical to `List<int> temp = new List<int>(); temp.Add(1); ... List<int> a = temp;`  That is, the `a` variable is not initialized until *after* all the adds are called.  Otherwise it would be legal to do something like `List<int> a = new List<int>() { a.Count, a.Count, a.Count };` which is a crazy thing to do.

Comment: @EricLippert, `List<int> a = new List<int>() { a.Count, a.Count, a.Count };` is not legal in either case because don't have a reference to at that point. I think his initial snippet was perfectly fine.

Comment: Nevermind, i see now. What your actual concern is this.. `List<int> a; a = new List<int>() {a.Count, a.Count, a.Count};` But this is definitely legal and there is nothing wrong with this because a.Count would get resolved before hand.

Comment: @user606723: There isn't any real difference between `List<int> a; a = new List<int>() { a.Count };` and `List<int> a = new List<int>() { a.Count };`

Comment: @Joren: You are correct; in fact the C# specification states that `T x = y;` is the same as `T x; x = y;`, This fact can lead to some odd situations. For instance, `int x = M(out x) + x;` is perfectly legal because `int x; x = M(out x) + x;` is legal.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare it's not necessary to implement `IEnumerable<T>`; the non-generic `IEnumerable` is enough to allow the use of collection initializer syntax.

Comment: @EricLippert and Joren, I stand corrected. That's very odd. I had no idea one could do that.

Comment: @user606723: Indeed you can. However, you may not do so and use var at the same time. You can't say `var x = M(out x) + x;` because we can't determine the type of x until we know the type of the initializer, but we can't determine the type of the initializer until overload resolution succeeds on M, and overload resolution cannot succeed until we know the type of x. Rather than try to solve this "chicken and egg" problem we simply give up.

Comment: @phoog: You're right, I'm just so used to favoring `IEnumerable<T>` over `IEnumerable`, corrected.

Comment: Eric's point is important if you're using some kind of collection that implements IDisposable. `using (var x = new Something{ 1, 2 })` won't dispose the object if one of the `Add` calls fails.

Answer (score 11):

It is so called [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

`List<T>` is the "simple" class, but compiler gives a special treatment to it in order to make your life easier.

This one is so called [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). You need to implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `Add` method.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [C# Version 3.0 Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#cs3spec_topic5) "The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied must be of a type that implements System.Collections.Generic.ICollection for exactly one T."

However, this information appears to be inaccurate as of this writing; see Eric Lippert's clarification in the comments below.

Comment: That page is not accurate. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. That must be some preliminary pre-release documentation that somehow never got deleted. The original design was to require ICollection, but that is not the final design we settled on.

Answer (score 6):

It works thanks to [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) which basically require the collection to implement an Add method and that will do the work for you.

Answer (score 6):

Another cool thing about collection initializers is that you can have multiple overloads of `Add` method and you can call them all in the same initializer! For example this works:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public void Add(T item, int number)
    {

    }
    public void Add(T item, string text) 
    {

    }
    public bool Add(T item) //return type could be anything
    {

    }
}

var myCollection = new MyCollection<bool> 
{
    true,
    { false, 0 },
    { true, "" },
    false
};
```

It calls the correct overloads. Also, it looks for just the method with name `Add`, the return type could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The array like syntax is being turned in a series of `Add()` calls.

To see this in a much more interesting example, consider the following code in which I do two interesting things that sound first illegal in C#, 1) setting a readonly property, 2) setting a list with a array like initializer.

```
public class MyClass
{   
    public MyClass()
    {   
        _list = new List<string>();
    }
    private IList<string> _list;
    public IList<string> MyList 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return _list;
        }
    }
}
//In some other method
var sample = new MyClass
{
    MyList = {"a", "b"}
};
```

This code will work perfectly, although 1) MyList is readonly and 2) I set a list with array initializer.

The reason why this works, is because in code that is part of an object intializer the compiler always turns any `{}` like syntax to a series of `Add()` calls which are perfectly legal even on a readonly field.