# Sort a List<T> by enum where enum is out of order

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a List of messages.
Each message has a type.

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Foo = 0,
    Bar = 1,
    Boo = 2,
    Doo = 3
}
```

The enum names are arbitrary and cannot be changed.

I need to return the list sorted as: Boo, Bar, Foo, Doo

My current solution is to create a tempList, add the values in the order I want, return the new list.

```
List<Message> tempList = new List<Message>();
tempList.AddRange(messageList.Where(m => m.MessageType == MessageType.Boo));
tempList.AddRange(messageList.Where(m => m.MessageType == MessageType.Bar));
tempList.AddRange(messageList.Where(m => m.MessageType == MessageType.Foo));
tempList.AddRange(messageList.Where(m => m.MessageType == MessageType.Doo));
messageList = tempList;
```

How can I do this with an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx)?

Comment: Write a new IComparer with a Compare method that returns -1, 0, and 1 based on the order of the enums you want. Should be fairly straightforward, what are you having issues with?

Comment: Yeah, Robert has it.  First you'll need to create an object that implements IComparer<MessageType> with a method that has the signature int Compare(MessageType first, MessageType second)  Next, fill in that method so it returns -1, 0, and 1 depending on the order that you want.  If you're having trouble implementing the method, post what you came up with so far and why it's not working

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, let's write our own comparer:

```
public class MyMessageComparer : IComparer<MessageType> {
    protected IList<MessageType> orderedTypes {get; set;}

    public MyMessageComparer() {
        // you can reorder it's all as you want
        orderedTypes = new List<MessageType>() {
            MessageType.Boo,
            MessageType.Bar,
            MessageType.Foo,
            MessageType.Doo,
        };
    }

    public int Compare(MessageType x, MessageType y) {
        var xIndex = orderedTypes.IndexOf(x);
        var yIndex = orderedTypes.IndexOf(y);

        return xIndex.CompareTo(yIndex);
    }
};
```

How to use:

```
messages.OrderBy(m => m.MessageType, new MyMessageComparer())
```

There is a easier way: just create ordereTypes list and use another overload of OrderBy:

```
var orderedTypes = new List<MessageType>() {        
            MessageType.Boo,
            MessageType.Bar,
            MessageType.Foo,
            MessageType.Doo,
    };

messages.OrderBy(m => orderedTypes.IndexOf(m.MessageType)).ToList();
```

Hm.. Let's try to take advantages from writing our own IComparer. Idea: write it like our last example but in some other semantic. Like this:

```
messages.OrderBy(
      m => m.MessageType, 
      new EnumComparer<MessageType>() { 
          MessageType.Boo, 
          MessageType.Foo }
);
```

Or this:

```
messages.OrderBy(m => m.MessageType, EnumComparer<MessageType>());
```

Okay, so what we need. Our own comparer:

1. Must accept enum as generic type ([how to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum))
2. Must be usable with collection initializer syntax ([how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853937/why-can-i-initialize-a-list-like-an-array-in-c))
3. Must sort by default order, when we have no enum values in our comparer (or some enum values aren't in our comparer)

So, here is the code:

```
public class EnumComparer<TEnum>: IComparer<TEnum>, IEnumerable<TEnum> where TEnum: struct, IConvertible {
    protected static IList<TEnum> TypicalValues { get; set; }

    protected IList<TEnum> _reorderedValues;

    protected IList<TEnum> ReorderedValues { 
        get { return _reorderedValues.Any() ? _reorderedValues : TypicalValues; } 
        set { _reorderedValues = value; }
    } 

    static EnumComparer() {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }

        TypicalValues = new List<TEnum>();
        foreach (TEnum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))) {
            TypicalValues.Add(value);
        };            
    }

    public EnumComparer(IList<TEnum> reorderedValues = null) {
        if (_reorderedValues == null ) {
            _reorderedValues = new List<TEnum>();

            return;
        }

        _reorderedValues = reorderedValues;
    }

    public void Add(TEnum value) {
        if (_reorderedValues.Contains(value))
            return;

        _reorderedValues.Add(value);
    }

    public int Compare(TEnum x, TEnum y) {
        var xIndex = ReorderedValues.IndexOf(x);
        var yIndex = ReorderedValues.IndexOf(y);

        // no such enums in our order list:
        // so this enum values must be in the end
        //   and must be ordered between themselves by default

        if (xIndex == -1) {
            if (yIndex == -1) {
                xIndex = TypicalValues.IndexOf(x);
                yIndex = TypicalValues.IndexOf(y);
                return xIndex.CompareTo(yIndex);                
            }

           return -1;
        }

        if (yIndex == -1) {
            return -1; //
        }

        return xIndex.CompareTo(yIndex);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        _reorderedValues = new List<TEnum>();
    }

    private IEnumerable<TEnum> GetEnumerable() {
        return Enumerable.Concat(
            ReorderedValues,
            TypicalValues.Where(v => !ReorderedValues.Contains(v))
        );
    }

    public IEnumerator<TEnum> GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerable().GetEnumerator();            
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerable().GetEnumerator();            
    }
}
```

So, well, let's make sorting more faster. We need to override default OrderBy method for our enums:

```
public static class LinqEnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TEnum>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TEnum> selector, EnumComparer<TEnum> enumComparer) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        foreach (var enumValue in enumComparer)
        {
            foreach (var sourceElement in source.Where(item => selector(item).Equals(enumValue)))
            {
                yield return sourceElement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, that's lazy. You can google how yield works. Well, let's test speed. Simple benchmark: http://pastebin.com/P8qaU20Y. Result for n = 1000000;

```
Enumerable orderBy, elementAt: 00:00:04.5485845
       Own orderBy, elementAt: 00:00:00.0040010
Enumerable orderBy, full sort: 00:00:04.6685977
       Own orderBy, full sort: 00:00:00.4540575
```

We see, that our own orderBy by is more lazy that standart order by (yeah, it doesn't need to sort everything). And faster even for fullsort.

Problems in this code: it doesn't support `ThenBy()`. If you need this, you can write your own linq extension that returns `IOrderedEnumerable` There are a [blog post series by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) which goes into LINQ to Objects in some depth, providing a complete alternative implementation. The basis of `IOrderedEnumerable` is covered in [part 26a](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/04/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26a-iorderedenumerable.aspx) and [26b](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/05/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26b-orderby-descending-thenby-descending.aspx), with more details and optimization in [26c](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/06/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26c-optimizing-orderedenumerable.aspx) and [26d](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early.aspx).

Answer (score 44):

An alternative to using `IComparer` would be to build an ordering dictionary.

```
var orderMap = new Dictionary<MessageType, int>() {
    { MessageType.Boo, 0 },
    { MessageType.Bar, 1 },
    { MessageType.Foo, 2 },
    { MessageType.Doo, 3 }
};

var orderedList = messageList.OrderBy(m => orderMap[m.MessageType]);
```

Comment: The funny thing is that what he has right now is a bucket sort and it's asymptotically faster than `OrderBy` (since I'm pretty sure it has to be comparison based). Something like this is more extensible and easier to maintain, but the time complexity may be worth noting if he is handling large data sets.

Comment: @roliu: I've proposed a different solution, which I think addresses both the maintenance and performance concerns.

Comment: @voithos I know this is older but, what would happen if there was a 5th type not included in the dictionary? Would it go at the back as 4, or the front as -1, or simply error out?

Comment: @WayneO: It will error out, in this case. Because the `OrderBy` is accessing values from the dictionary directly (instead of, e.g., using something like [this GetValueOrDefault extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2601501/716118)) it will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` when the lookup fails. To account for this, you could change the lambda to use something akin to `GetValueOrDefault` mentioned above: `m => orderMap.GetValueOrDefault(m.MessageType, -1)`.

Comment: @voithos This approach together with `GetValueOrDefault` is a very nice approach as you can decide how to handle the values and the default. When the enum is enlarged, the default gives a default position at the beginning or end. Or if many enum values do not matter and are priorized in the middle, you can do that too. Nice!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using an `IComparer`, you could also use a `SelectMany` approach, which should have better performance for large message lists, if you have a fixed number of message types.

```
var messageTypeOrder = new [] {
    MessageType.Boo,
    MessageType.Bar,
    MessageType.Foo,
    MessageType.Doo,
};

List<Message> tempList = messageTypeOrder
    .SelectMany(type => messageList.Where(m => m.MessageType == type))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Cool. I think I would try and write it more closely to bucket sort so like `messageTypeOrder.Select(t => messageList.Where(m => m.MessageType == t).SelectMany(b => b)` but not a big deal. It's probably more important what sort of looks you'd get if you tried checking in this code for work :)

Comment: @roliu: Honest question: how is that closer to a bucket sort?  Given the lazy nature of linq, I don't see what the difference is.

Comment: It's probably just a preference sort of thing. I think of the steps of bucket sort as: 1) Split list into buckets 2) Merge buckets. I think of LINQ left to right/top to bottom. So in your code, I see a merge which takes the buckets as an input (2 then 1). In my code I see the buckets and then the merge (1 then 2). I guess your way is actually truer to the spirit of LINQ in that it's more mathematical (the outermost function is the last "step") while mine is more imperative/may be more familiar to novices.

Comment: Hey guys, why we can't make lazy version of bucket sort? The real problem that I don't know how to override linq OrderBy method

Answer (score 2):

You may avoid writing a completely new type just to implement IComparable. Use the Comparer class instead:

```
IComparer<Message> comparer = Comparer.Create<Message>((message) =>
    {
    // lambda that compares things
    });
tempList.Sort(comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a mapping dictionary dynamically from the `Enum` values with **LINQ** like this:

```
  var mappingDIctionary = new List<string>((string[])Enum.GetNames(typeof(Hexside)))
                    .OrderBy(label => label )
                    .Select((i,n) => new {Index=i, Label=n}).ToList();
```

Now any new values added to the Enum n future will automatically get properly mapped.

Also, if someone decides to renumber, refactor, or reorder the enumeration, everything is handled automatically.

**Update:** 
As pointed out below, Alphabetical ordering was not called for; rather a semi- alphabetical ordering, so essentially random.  Although not an answer to this particular question, this technique might be useful to future visitors, so I will leave it standing.

Comment: That mappingDictionary isn't really a `Dictionary`, it's a `List` of dynamic pairs. Also, if I'm not mistaken, the OP asked for `Boo` to be ordered before `Bar`, but they are not ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

No need to have the mapping. This should give you the list and order based on the enum. You don't have to modify anything even when you change the enum's order or and new items...

```
var result = (from x in tempList
              join y in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MessageType)).Cast<MessageType>()
              on x equals y
              orderby y
              select y).ToList();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as it would sort according to the enumeration order (Foo,Bar,Boo,Doo) - the question was how to give them a custom order (Boo,Barr,Foo,Doo).

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to get this working with Entity Framework (EF), you would have to spread out your enum in your `OrderBy` as such:

```
messageList.OrderBy(m => 
    m.MessageType == MessageType.Boo ? 0 :
    m.MessageType == MessageType.Bar ? 1 :
    m.MessageType == MessageType.Foo ? 2 :
    m.MessageType == MessageType.Doo ? 3 : 4
);
```

This creates a sub select with `CASE WHEN`, then `ORDER BY` on that temporary column.