# Translate "Multilanguage" enum javascript/c#

Tags: c#, javascript, sorting, enums

I have following problem.
In my server side code I have an enumeration  that defines the Type of Task I have.
In my front en webpage I show all my tasks in a table that contains the column "Task Type".
This column actually shows the enumeration  value translated with lingua JavaScript library.

So in my JavaScript Library I have something like this for English

```
enumTaskType_0  => "Unknown"
enumTaskType_1  => "Problem"
enumTaskType_2  => "Incident"
enumTaskType_3  => "Change Request"
```

and for German

```
enumTaskType_0  => "Unbekannt"
enumTaskType_1  => "Problem"
enumTaskType_2  => "Ticket"
enumTaskType_3  => "Änderungsantrag"
```

my c# enumeration obviously is then

```
public enum SupportTaskType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Problem= 1,
    Incident= 2,
    Change Request= 3
}
```

Now my Problem:
All columns in my table should be Sortable. It sorts alright.. but the sorting is done with the Value of the enumeration, so in all languages it's sorted differently..

I mean it is technically sorted, but for the user its is more like "grouped" and not alphabetically sorted.

Any suggestions?

I was thinking that I could send a JSON from my JavaScript to my Server and implement something like in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308818/sort-a-listt-by-enum-where-enum-is-out-of-order)...

But there must be a better way!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than producing the html with server code, I assume that that's the way you're doing it, I would create and array (with the number concatenated) and after your translator executes I would user [Array.sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) and then split each value.

```
var taskType = ["Unknown|1", "Problem|2", "Incident|3", "Change Request|4"];
taskType.sort();
```

Comment: Oh no I'm not producing any HTML from the server. I'm getting a JSON object with an array of objects in the Javascript and then I'm binding that array with knockout.js

Comment: Problem is I can't sort it on the client. I need t go get the data sorted from the server. I have a paging on my view

Comment: You've answered your own question then. I don't see the point of this exercise...