# Why I can't make my constructor for attributes?

Tags: c#, oop

I need to initialize this list and it should be static, but I can't. Any help, please :(

```
private static List<MyObj> teste;

public static List<MyObj> Teste;
{
    get {return Teste;}
    set
    {
        teste.Add(new MyObj{ Value = 1, Quant = 1 });
        teste.Add(new MyObj{ Value = 2, Quant = 1 });
        teste.Add(new MyObj{ Value = 99, Quant = 1 });
        teste.Add(new MyObj{ Value = 33, Quant = 1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static List<MyObj> teste = new List<MyObj>() { new MyObj{ Value = 1, Quant = 1 }, new MyObj{ Value = 2, Quant = 1 }, new MyObj{ Value = 99, Quant = 1 }, new MyObj{ Value = 33, Quant = 1 }}`

Comment: Thanks a lot GSerg! It worked, but I didn't understand why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8853937/11683

Comment: I think I got it now :)

Comment: There is no attributes in your post *at all*. Please check if your question is about C# or some other langauge.

Answer (score 2):

Before using `teste` you need to instantiate a list of myobj:

```
private static List<MyObj> teste = new List<MyObj>();
```

And the `get` of your property can't return itself, it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I have already coded it before Bruno, and it didn't work. I use the code from GSerg and it worked. But I didn't understand why.  Thank you anyway.